# How to interpret output from three-piece linear regression in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, piecewise

I have a three-piece linear regression model that I’m running in R to model body mass over age in a large population. My dataset is called hdata. Through an iterative procedure that runs through all combinations of breaks points, I have found the two breakpoints associated with the lowest residual squared error model. The code for my piecewise regression, with the two breakpoints specified is:

```
piecewise=lm(hdata$weight ~ hdata$age*(hdata$age < 0.7) + hdata$age*(hdata$age>=0.7 & hdata$age<2) + hdata$age*(hdata$age>2))
```

When I look at:

```
summary(piecewise)
```

I get the following output:

```
                                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                     1723.012    210.042   8.203 3.67e-16 ***
hdata$age                                         18.494      1.089  16.975  < 2e-16 ***
hdata$age < 0.7TRUE                            -1690.051    210.476  -8.030 1.48e-15 ***
hdata$age >= 0.7 & hdata$age < 2TRUE            -721.200    213.882  -3.372 0.000758 ***
hdata$age > 2TRUE                                478.094    210.194   2.275 0.023016 *  
hdata$age:hdata$age < 0.7TRUE                   2022.896     45.477  44.481  < 2e-16 ***
hdata$age:hdata$age >= 0.7 & hdata$age < 2TRUE   603.453     30.532  19.764  < 2e-16 ***
hdata$age:hdata$age > 2TRUE                           NA         NA      NA       NA
```

From these estimates, I would like to calculate the three intercepts, and the three slopes associated with the model, but I do not know how to do this. For simplicity, I’m calling the estimate associated with (Intercept) Est1, the estimate associated with hdata$age Est2, and so on…up to Est7. I think that the first intercept should be Est1 + Est3, and the first slope should be Est2 + Est6, but I could be wrong about that, and still don’t know how to calculate the other intercepts and slopes. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you have a look at package "segmented".

Comment: #Roland: Thanks very much. I actually originally tried it with that package, but found that the results were heavily dependent on the initial estimates that it required me to provide - altering those slightly gave widely different results. That's why I wanted to try running it without that package.

Comment: can you provide a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-00)? I'm worried that the model you've constructed is not piecewise *continuous*, i.e. the value can jump at the breakpoints (which I would guess is undesirable).  If you're having trouble with the `segmented` package it would also make me worry that your problem is in some way unstable ...

Comment: @BenBolker: I hadn't considered the fact that I didn't make it continuous - you're probably right and I'll need to fix that. I'm just figuring out how to make a reproducible example for this, since my dataset is pretty large. I'll try to provide one shortly.